# Parsing XML Response from web

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm trying to parse [this](https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/52456930/summary?season=SEASON2016&api_key=2c0543ab-aeca-476d-8276-a5c23748898c) using `requests.get` and `ElementTree` with parse from string and it keeps telling me that it's a bad XML file:

> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0.

I fetch the response from the API with requests and I tried to use different parsers.
Here is what I'm trying:

```
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree

url = 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/52456930/summary?season=SEASON2016&api_key=2c0543ab-aeca-476d-8276-a5c23748898c'
response = requests.get(url)
xmlstring = response.content # or response.text i dont know

parser = ElementTree.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
ElementTree.fromstring(xmlstring, parser=parser)`
```

I need to parse it in order to ask a specific var from it.

Comment: It looks more like JSON. Use `json.loads`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), not [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML).

You can use the python `json` library to parse it into a normal python dictionary.

```
import requests, json

url = 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/52456930/summary?season=SEASON2016&api_key=2c0543ab-aeca-476d-8276-a5c23748898c'

response = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(response.content)

for stat in data['playerStatSummaries']:
    print stat['wins']
```

**Output**

```
14
143
21
1
0
0
8
36
545
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works perfectly and i'm still trying to fetch 'wins' for each game type, such as 'Coopvsai' or 'Unranked', because every player doesnt have the 'wins' set in the same order.